# React / React Native: can't setState using key from previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, setstate

Struggling to see what the difference is between these two snippets:

**State is NOT set**

```js
handleAddItemToCart = (item) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const { cartItems } = state;
      item.quantity = 1;
      cartItems.push(item);
      return { cartItems };
    });
  }
```

**State IS set**

```js
<...>
return { cartItems: [...cartItems] }
```

It's not actually an issue for me as I have it working, but I'd really like to understand what's going on here - what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If anyone fancies editing the question title so it's a bit clearer, I'd be grateful

Comment: You are mutating the array. If you really want to do that use `shouldComponentUpdate` to compare old and new values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by pushing to the array, you mutate both the previous and the current state. While React does not care about, `shouldComponentUpdate` does, as it cannot decide wether the current state differs the previous state, as you mutated both.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // does return false, although you mutated the state
  return nextState.items !== this.state.items;
}
```

That said, the bulletproof, completely immutable way would be:

```
this.setState({ cardItems }) => ({ cartItems: [...cardItems, { ...item, quantity: 1 }] }));
```

Comment: Ah, OK, that make sense, thanks - `shouldComponentUpdate` was the missing piece of the puzzle. Possibly relevant: I found this in the React docs - "In the future React may treat shouldComponentUpdate() as a hint rather than a strict directive, and returning false may still result in a re-rendering of the component."